# PDE: What technique to apply solving inhomogeneous heat equations on the form $y_t - y_{xx} = - Ky $ with homog. IC and BC

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Presented with the below inhomogeneous heat equation PDE, the term $Cu$ is posing a challenge as it makes an inhomogeneous version of the standard heat equation:

$y_t - y_{xx} = - Ky , \qquad K > 0, \qquad t > 0, \qquad 0 < x < 1$

$K$ is a constant

Is it possible to use separation of variables on this, or is there supposed to be another approach to solving these types of problems?

These homogeneous conditions apply in my case:

BCs: $ \qquad y(0,t) = y(1,t) = 0 $

ICs: $\qquad y(0,0) = y(1,0) = 0$

Comment: If you have a separable solution $y(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ then you have $T'X-TX''=-KTX$, so (ignoring division by zero for the moment) $\frac{T'}{T}-\frac{X''}{X}=-K$. So take $X$ to be an eigenfunction of the second derivative operator with your boundary conditions with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $T$ should be an eigenfunction of the first derivative operator with eigenvalue $\lambda-K$.

Comment: Your ICs are the special cases of BCs, so the ICs are equivalent to be none.